# Disable Airdroid keyboard by default

Tags: keyboard, airdroid

My problem is that whenever I connect to my Android 7 phone via Airdroid Mirror on Windows 10 the Airdroid keyboard gets activated. Of course I can deactivate the keyboard by clicking the keyboard button on the function bar but this is annoying. I don't want to do this every time.

How can the Airdroid keyboard be disabled by default?

Comment: Do you see any related entry under Settings -> Language and Input -> Keyboards?

Comment: @Firelord Unfortunately not. What shall I do?